# What does the button "padme" do in Alien?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-1979

Whilst Ripley is launching the *Nostromo* self destruct, she uses this panel with some interesting buttons:

[image]

The image is from [TypeSetInTheFuture.com](https://typesetinthefuture.com/2014/12/01/alien/). Some of the buttons are:

- PRANIC LIFT 777
- LINGHA
- YONI
- SHAKTI EXCESS
- AGARIC FLY
- And of course, PADME

Now **out of universe** these terms were taken from a Hindu book:

> Well, according to the [Alien Explorations blog](http://alienexplorations.blogspot.co.uk/1979/05/simon-deerings-auto-destruct-panel.html), designer Simon Deering needed some complex-sounding labels for the keyboard at short notice. He was reading The Secret Doctrine by Helena Blavatsky, a Russian philosopher and occultist, at the time of filming. Blavatsky’s book attempts to explain the origin and evolution of the universe in terms derived from the Hindu concept of cyclical development. Deering found his inspiration in its pages, and the Nostromo‘s odd keyboard was born.

But my question is, **what is the function of the buttons in-universe?**

Comment: I'm reasonably sure that Lingha and Yoni are Sanskrit words for one's *naughty parts*.

Comment: anyone realizing, that `hum` is left of `padme`, that makes me think of the snskrit mantra [Om mani padme hum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Om_mani_padme_hum)

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer this. You've already highlighted why the symbols and writing were there out-of-universe (the set-designer wanted to make them look fancy) and what they were for in-universe (they controlled the self-destruct mechanism). What else are you hoping for?

Comment: @Valorum: I'm asking for the detailed explanation, button-by-button. E.g. the Padme button might arm the warheads, and the Pranic lift might move them inline with the fuel to ensure destruction etc. (if that explanation exists)

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PlotSensitiveButton

Comment: @Accio_Answer - I think your own links make it clear that it's just a "[generic control panel with lots of buttons](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BillionsOfButtons)*". The buttons don't button anything

Comment: For the record, this isn't an explosive self-destruct. It's the engine's cooling system. There are no warheads.

Comment: @Valorum: Fair point - the in-depth explanation may just be 'I picked these names because they sounded cool...', but it's worth leaving the question just in-case a novelisation explains the self-destruct sequence in any detail

Comment: @Accio_Answer - It doesn't even mention them: *"Gauges and controls functioned patiently within, waiting to be told what to do. There was one particular board whose switches were outlined in red. She studied it a moment, recalling sequences, then began to close the switches one at a time.
One double switch lay protected beneath a locked cover. She pried at it a moment, then stepped back and hammered it loose with the butt end of the flamethrower, moved up, and threw the dual control."*

Comment: @Valorum: your last comment sounds like a solid answer to me.

Comment: I mean, "Agaric Fly" is just flipped words from Fly Agaric, a [mushroom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amanita_muscaria). I don't think there is any rhyme or reason to the actual buttons' names.

Comment: Out of curiosity, in what way does the below answer your question. It provides no additional details to your question.

Comment: @Edlothiad: Given that the question has been 'unanswered' for a year, I took Kevin's out -of-universe answer with Valorum's in-universe comment to form my own conclusion: Simon Deering liked The Secret Doctrine and swiped some words from there.

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood your post. I understood it to be asking what function the buttons had, not "where did the labels come from"

Comment: @Edlothiad: It was originally, but Valorum's quote of the novelisation made that question moot. Preferably Valorum would have answered with an answer, rather than a comment.

Comment: As always you're welcome to compile the information you've gathered to answer your own question. If the premise of the question has changed, the body should be reflected to show that.

Comment: Isn't the answer simply that pushing the Padme button causes the user to lose the will to live?

Comment: Not an answer, but interesting: https://www.reddit.com/r/MovieDetails/comments/hrmbdr/the_person_in_charge_of_the_nostromo_set_from/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share

Answer (score 3):

The button is never observed to be physically pressed "in-universe" -- so we have to infer what might happen from the universe of our own imagination, and experience.

Padme is Sanskrit for the lotus flower. The lotus flower symbolizes the promise of enlightenment in Eastern ideologies - for example:

> "In Hinduism, the lotus flower is very significant as it relates to the sacred Padma lotus, and is associated with numerous gods, including Vishnu, Lakshmi and Brahma. In many ancient works of art, the gods are depicted with lotus flowers as they represent purity and divinity"
>   https://www.onetribeapparel.com/blogs/pai/meaning-of-lotus-flower

In-universe the obvious parallel to the Padma Lotus is David's tempting, but face-hugger-spewing, egg.

[image: The Illuminating Alien Egg]

There was never any guarantee that the actual state of existence confired upon the "enlightened" would be healthy for the confirmant crew of the [Nostromo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nostromo) deep in the [heart of darkness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heart_of_Darkness)... of Space; and that fact is borne out by the consummate fate of first the captain and then his entire crew, each cocooned into their own living hells - including Ripley who ultimately plunged into the furnace in Alien3.

As Mother revealed -- the crew was always expendable in the context of the company's desire to achieve its collective, self-worshiping, goal.

## Ripley fell into the furnace

-- **That's what happened when the Wayland-Yutani Corporate-Collective gave in to the temptation of David's button, and tried to become as God, in-universe**

The Horror!